# How do I completely purge and disable the default channel in Anaconda and switch to conda-forge?

Tags: python, anaconda

Is there a way to completely purge and disable the `defaults` channel in Anaconda and switch to `conda-forge`? The reason is that Anaconda [term of service](https://www.anaconda.com/terms-of-service) limits the use of its repository to non-commercial activities. Switching to conda-forge avoids the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically, it should be sufficient to remove it from the `channels` configuration option, which corresponds to the user-level configuration file (`~/.condarc`). This could just be `defaults`, but check to see if you also need to remove `anaconda`, `main`, `r`, `pro`, or other [subchannels of `defaults`](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/using-repositories/).

```bash
# check what is currently set
conda config --show channels

# remove what you find 
conda config --remove channels defaults

# add conda-forge
conda config --add channels conda-forge
```

If this is not sufficient, one can use `conda config --show-sources` (as suggested by @CorneliusRoemer) to list the locations whence Conda is loading configuration settings (`.condarc` files, environment variables), as well as the content of each source. This should help in tracking down any atypical specifications of unwanted channels.

Alternatively, you may consider installing [a Miniforge **base**](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#miniforge) (or a variant), which only includes **conda-forge** channel by default.

---

### *nodefaults* option

Mentioned in [the Conda docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.1/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) is a `nodefaults` channel option for overriding channel settings. For example, this is useful for YAML files to prevent users with `defaults` in the `.condarc` from using it during environment creation. Example,

**YAML Snippet**

```yaml
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - nodefaults
```

Note that this only works with Conda YAML files. The code is specific to the `conda env` subcommand and directs the solver to skip loading additional channels from the configuration *context*. It should also not be exonFor `conda create` or `conda install` commands, there is the `--override-channels` argument with equivalent functionality.

Comment: I found `conda config --show-sources` really helpful to figure out why I still had defaults somewhere. I tried `nodefaults` in my `.condarc` but it didn't work. I think this is purely for environment files read in to create the environment - maybe worth adding to the answer.

Comment: Somehow this is absolutely ignored by my conda. In `show channels` I see only conda-forge. Still, if I do `conda install` immediately in same terminal window, the `defaults` channel is picked up. In `.condarc` I also see only `conda-forge`. Only ideas? Debian-based Docker container.

Comment: @Valeria The `defaults` channel is hard-coded by the Miniconda and Anaconda installers. Users that install Miniforge will not have this problem. Using the `--override-channels` argument will exclude `defaults`, but then one must manually add back in all channels needed, e.g., `-c conda-forge -c bioconda` etc.